# Keeping tabindex independent when multiple forms are on one page

Tags: html, forms

I have two forms on my page, both have tabindexes on the form elements within in each form.

The problem I have is that they don't act independent of each other. So when I am in Form1 and want to tab to the next element, it is instead tabbing across to the second field on Form2 instead.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rdr7fv1/) to show you what I mean.

And here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <input name="Forename" type="text" id="Forename" placeholder="Forename" tabindex="1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="Surname" type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="Surname" tabindex="2">
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <input name="EMail" type="text" id="EMail" placeholder="EMail" tabindex="1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2">
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Tabindex is part of the document scope, not per form. So you should start the tabindex of the 2nd form with 3.

Comment: @RenéGeuze This is worth an answer. =)

Comment: @FabianMebus True, it is. I just thought it was too obvious and not complete enough to be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabindex is part of the document scope, not per form. So you should start the tabindex of the 2nd form with 3.

Comment: there's no way around this? this is a real bummer because it means everytime i change the tabindex in one form, i'll have to change it in all the forms on the page

Comment: You can leave numbers between every tabindex. So you number with 10, 20, 30, 40. So you can add some inbetween. The other option would be to not do it manually by either server or client side scripting.

Answer (score 2):

a workaround can be to use **tabindex="0"** on all fields, this will pick next field on tab click -> [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex).

Answer (score 1):

Going off of René's comment, I found this solution where I use a multiplier for each form section. In this case I'm using `Math.pow(10, form_index)` to generate this:

```
<form class='form-1'>
  <input type='text' tabindex='10' />
  <input type='text' tabindex='11' />
  <input type='text' tabindex='12' />
</form>
<form class='form-2'>
  <input type='text' tabindex='100' />
  <input type='text' tabindex='101' />
  <input type='text' tabindex='102' />
</form>
<form class='form-3'>
  <input type='text' tabindex='1000' />
  <input type='text' tabindex='1001' />
  <input type='text' tabindex='1002' />
</form>
```